# How do I categorize my data for a datamining procedure?

Tags: r, apriori, categorical-data

I am doing a data mining procedure, using the `apriori` function. This function only works on categorical data, without values but only text. My dataset fulfills these requirements, as I have five categorial variables, without numerical values but only text (so the variable 'sex' is categorized into 'female' and 'male')

If I now try the `apriori()` function, I get the following error:

```
apriori(data)
```

Error in `asMethod(object)` :

```
  column(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 not logical or a factor. Use as.factor or categorize first.
```

Although my data looks categorical, R does not get that it is. How do I use for instance the as.factor function to categorize my data properly, so that the apriori function works?

Comment: I have tried to make factors of each column.. perhaps I should do that for each variable and then use cbind them again into a matrix?

Answer (score 5):

You can convert all your columns to a factor:

```
data <- sapply(data,as.factor)
```

Comment: After doing what you suggested now i get the following error: Error in t(as(from, "ngCMatrix")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': Error in asMethod(object) : cannot coerce 'NA's to "nsparseMatrix"

Comment: For me it worked after turning it into a data frame like data <- data.frame(sapply(data,as.factor))

Answer (score 1):

For me

`data <- data.frame(sapply(data,as.factor))
rules<- apriori(data)`

Works well