# Issue in factoring or categorizing data in apriori algorithm

Tags: r, apriori

I am trying to find association rules using Apriori algorithm in R.

When I do the following, an error is thrown.

```
rules <- apriori(groceries, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.5))
```

> Error : column(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 not logical or a factor. Use as.factor
>   or categorize first.

Similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161530/how-do-i-categorize-my-data-for-a-datamining-procedure/52020026#52020026).

I understand that column values should be categorical in order to perform this algorithm on the data set and answer provided there was perfectly alright.

For example if I have a data frame named `groceries` and columns `"food"`, `"medicine"`, etc, calling `is.factor(groceries$food)` throws following error.

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I am wondering calling **is.factor(groceries$food)** should return **TRUE** as we converted entire data frame into factors. But if I do,

```
groceries[] <- lapply(groceries, factor)
```

I was able to get **TRUE** for calling **is.factor()** method.

What has happened here? What is the difference between above two methods. Both work fine but I came across this question. Any explanations for this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Nil - t's hard to help you with a data question when we have to imagine your data.  Use `dput(head(groceries))` to copy/paste your data out of R so that we can see what you're working with. Thanks!

Comment: ensure that `groceries` is a data frame and use the code  `groceries[] <- lapply(as.data.frame(groceries), function(x) as.factor(x))` instead, it should work.